# Do we have any superfan(atics)?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, fun

I crossed the threshold for the [Fanatic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/badges/23/fanatic) badge some time ago, and have been idly wondering how long I can keep up my consecutive visits. I stumbled across a [previously-achieved goal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/6761/jasonwryan) of 1500 days and wondered: do we have any super fanatics -- users with a high number of consecutive visits?

Comment: How do I see how many days I've visited continuously ? I tried looking, but didn't find anything.

Comment: I don't know how to see it in the app, but from the web page, click on your name at the top, then on the Profile "tab"; the consecutive count is on the right.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sitting on [2282 as of today](https://ptpb.pw/vTBM.png).

Comment: I've got to ask... how many of those via shell/Perl/Python/Ruby/etc. script? :-P

Comment: I was at 2215 when I broke the streak; it's kind of nice not needing to worry if I've missed a day anymore

Answer (score 2):

As a point of reference, as of today I have: "visited 779 days, 779 consecutive".